# How to fix can't convert string to double error after converting it

Tags: c#

I am very new to Xamarin and a little but confused but I when applying a code get this error:

```
can't convert string to double error after converting it.
```

My code is this:
DATA.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Orbage
{
    public class DATA
    {
        public string Label = "USA";
        public string Address = "This is the US";
        public string Lat = "40.060407";
        public string Lng = "-102.453091";


    }
    




}
```

and my main page is this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Orbage
{
    class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap
            {
                MapType = MapType.Street

            };
            // ...
            Content = customMap;

            var json = File.ReadAllText("DATA");
            NumberFormatInfo provider = new NumberFormatInfo();
            provider.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            provider.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
            double doubleVal = Convert.ToDouble("855.65", provider);

            var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DATA>>(json);
            foreach (var place in places)
            {
                CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(place.Lat,place.Lng),
                    Label = place.Label,
                    Address = place.Address,
                    Name = "Xamarin",

                    Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                };



                customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };

                customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even after doing this I receive this error.
How can I fix this or make any changes to my code so there is no need in doubling it.
If my code seems confusing I have basically created custom maps and instead of creating a million pins writing all the code in a data script . When I try to apply it I get this error.
Is there a better way to write it which avoids doubling it or can you please tell me how to convert it.
PLease help me. Thanks a lot!

Error in this line:
Position = new Position(place.Lat,place.Lng),

Comment: The exception is not in convert.ToDouble. Can you please tell me in which line the error comes?

Comment: Position = new Position(place.Lat,place.Lng) Its here.

Comment: Lat and Lng are string fields and I suppose that a new Position requires two doubles. So you need to convert them yourself

Comment: Please update your question with Postion class code

Comment: Thats what I tried to do here : NumberFormatInfo provider = new NumberFormatInfo();
            provider.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            provider.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";

Comment: Position class code???? I din't understand. I didn't create a new class for that. Just a data class

Comment: Please answer it.

Comment: Pls answer my question. Thanks alot!

Comment: @VimalCK  pls answer me.

Comment: @HansKesting pls answer me

Comment: You are never using that NumberFormatInfo in then problematic line - it doesn't automatically use some variable that you created elsewhere.

Comment: Either change your DATA class to use a "double" datatype for Lat and Lng (and fix the deserialisation) or convert the strings to double when using them to create a new Position

Comment: @HansKesting thanks but how can I change the data class to use a double pls put in answer.

Comment: new Position(place.Lat,place.Lng). The exception is happening inside this class. You have to post the Position class code to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `DATA` class `Lat` and `Lng` are defined as strings.  You need to convert them to `double`, which is what `Position` requires

```
Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat),Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
```